# jQuery datepicker with masked input onchange

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, onchange, mask

I have a series of date input text fields in an html document. When the value is changed, I want to fire the onchange event to do some stuff.

I have set the datepicker for these date fields to make it easier for the user to select a date.

I have also set the mask on these fields `.mask('99/99/99?99')` so they see the format desired and so they don't have to enter the slashes.

When I implement BOTH the datepicker and the mask on the fields and click on them then click out, the onchange event fires, even though I haven't changed anything in the field. If I remove the mask the datepicker works without firing onchange unless the field is changed. If I remove the datepicker and leave the mask on the fields and click in and out the onchange does not fire unless I changed the field. It is only when I combine the mask and the datepicker that when I click in and out the onchange fires regardless.

Is there a way to mask the input in the datepicker without using the separate mask() call on the fields? Is there a way in the datepicker to determine if the field actually changed?

Here's an example to try yourself.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPage(){
            $('input.datepicker').datepicker().mask('99/99/99?99');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadPage();">
    Try it: <input type="text" onchange="alert('changed, do some stuff');" class="datepicker" />
</body>
</html>
```